# How can I format this string in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, devexpress

I'm trying to convert a program that uses parts in Winforms, to WPF. I have run into a bit of trouble with this part. The program does this:

```
this.textBox.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "#,#;-#,#;-";
```

I'm not really sure what this is doing and I'm struggling to convert it to XAML for WPF. I know that I have to set it in here:

```
Text="{Binding x, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{...}}"/>
```

but I'm not sure what would be the equivalent, since `#,#;-#,#;-` does not work. Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: `Text="{Binding x, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:#,#;-#,#;-}}"/>` should work just fine. Please fix your post so that it includes _actual_ code in the form of a [mcve], along with a precise explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [WinForms Format Specifiers](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2141/common-features/formatting-values/format-specifiers), your original format string is saying:

1. You want positive decimal numbers to look like whole numbers #,# (Example: 1234.5 will look like 1,234)
2. You want negative decimal numbers to look like whole numbers -#,# (Example: -1234.5 will look like -1,234)
3. You want zero to look like - (Example: -)

For WPF, you can use those same string format specifiers, but you need to pre-pend the formation with a `{}`.  This is needed or else WPF will get confused with other markup extensions.

Here's an example:

**Main.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1, StringFormat={}{0:#,#;-#,#;-}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value2, StringFormat={}{0:#,#;-#,#;-}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value3, StringFormat={}{0:#,#;-#,#;-}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Main.xaml.cs**

```
public double Value1 { get; set; }
public double Value2 { get; set; }
public double Value3 { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Value1 = 1234567.890f;
    Value2 = -987654.321f;
    Value3 = 0;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Here's the final output:

[image]